# Why does an Expression type in .NET allows construction from a function but not conversion from one?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Why does expr1 compile but not expr2?

```
Func<object> func = () => new object();
Expression<Func<object>> expr1 = () => new object();
Expression<Func<object>> expr2 = func; //Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<object>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<object>>'
```

Comment: Lots of good explanations below, but remember you can always do this if it suits your needs: `Func<object> func = () => new object();  Expression<Func<object>> expr2 = () => func();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Func<T>` is a delegate (a pointer to a function), while an `Expression<Func<T>>` is an expression tree (a tree-like data structure that describes an operation). It follows that you cannot assign one to the other, as they are completely dissimilar.

When you assign a lambda function directly to a `Func<T>` the compiler compiles the code for your function and assigns a pointer to the compiled code to e.g. `func`.

On the other hand, when you assign a lambda function directly to an `Expression<Func<T>>` the compiler builds up the expression tree (which is simply an instance of a reference type) and assigns a reference to that object to e.g. `expr1`. This is just a convenience that the compiler provides to you, giving you a much more attractive option than manually constructing the expression tree yourself in code (which of course is also completely possible).

Comment: Ah but of course - the compiler sees different (unrelated) types. And I guess the compiler isn't able to "examine" `func` to find that it's a lambda expression (you can probably tell I'm not a compiler designer)?

Comment: @Christian a lambda has no CLR type. You cannot "store" a lambda anywhere. You can convert it to something else but then it is not a lambda anymore. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert between `Func` and `Expression` types. But you can convert from a lambda to either of them.

A lambda has a special type that **only exists in the C# type system**. The CLR does not know what a lambda is. Only the C# compiler knows that and the only operations that you can do with a lambda is to convert to the `Func` and `Expression` types. (This means that you cannot invoke a lambda for example as it has no CLR type at all).

That is why you observe a "semantic gap" here.

Answer (score 2):

In simpler words the compiler can convert a chunk of code (*Lambda* expression) into

- an `Expression`
- ***or*** a `Func`

This happens immediately when used, then the code is gone, converted non-reversible.
But `Func` and `Expression` are completely different types.

That's why you can't

```
Expression<Func<object>> expr2 = func;
```

But the other way around would work with

```
Func<object> func2 = expr1.Compile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `System.Func<object>` and `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<object>>` are different types. You can't implicitly convert them.

`Func<T>` is a delegate. Look at from *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)*.

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the T parameter.

`Expression<Func<T>>` is a expression tree.

Comment: @miniBill Because C# allows implicit conversion from a lambda to either type.